# I am trying to perform one hot encoding for a three sets of data

Tags: python, pandas, list, one-hot-encoding

I have a list (length=228) that represents the label of the columns (i.e column.head).Also, I have three samples (a,b,c), for each of these samples, I have to create one-hot encoding. How to do this. The result may look like a matrix with o and one values inside with dimension (3,228)

```
a='95', '66', '137', '70', '20'
b='36', '66', '44', '214', '105', '133'
c='170', '66', '97', '153', '105', '138'
lnew=list(range(1,229))
lnew=list(map(str, total_labels))
print(lnew)
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use sklearn, or are you being asked to do this from scratch? https://thecleverprogrammer.com/2020/08/27/one-hot-encoding-in-machine-learning/

Comment: @NewCoder18 I could not able to do this, I tried creating an empty array of size `z=np. zeros(3,228)`. Then I tried to assign the value to the `z[0,0]=a` but I am getting an error. could you suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

You create a list called matrice and you add sublists for each row with 1 if index matching 0 else

```
a=[95, 66, 137, 70, 20]
b=[36, 66, 44, 214, 105, 133]
c=[170, 66, 97, 153, 105, 138]

matrice=[]
matrice.append([1 if i in a else 0 for i in range(229)])
matrice.append([1 if i in b else 0 for i in range(229)])
matrice.append([1 if i in c else 0 for i in range(229)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
a=[95, 66, 137, 70, 20]
b=[36, 66, 44, 214, 105, 133]
c=[170, 66, 97, 153, 105, 138]

df = pd.DataFrame()
count=0
for j in [a,b,c]:
    col = [1 if i in j else 0 for i in range(229)]
    df[count] = col
    count+=1
mat = np.matrix(df).reshape(3,228)
```